# VB.NET form filling value isn't visible

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm trying to fill a PDF Form File with **iTextSharp** (version *5.5.13*).

My code doesn't work, the fields in the PdfFile are empty:

```
Dim pdfreader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(My.Resources.Dienstnachweis_BRK_Bereitschaft_Münchberg)
Dim pdfStamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(pdfreader, New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite), "\0", True)
pdfreader.RemoveUsageRights()
Dim pdfformfields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields
pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Datum", txtdatum.Text)
pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Veranstaltung", txtdatum.Text)
pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Dienstverantwortlicher", txtel.Text)
pdfformfields.SetField("Datum", txtdatum.Text, txtdatum.Text, True)
pdfformfields.SetField("Veranstaltung", txtdienstname.Text, txtdienstname.Text, True)
pdfformfields.SetField("Ort", txtdienstname.Text, txtdienstname.Text, True)
pdfformfields.SetField("Dienstverantworlicher", txtel.Text, txtel.Text, True)
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = False

pdfStamper.Close()
pdfreader.Close()
Process.Start(folderPath & "Dienstnachweis vom " & Now.ToShortDateString & ".pdf")
```

[My PDF file](http://hannes-ittner.de/Downloads/Dienstnachweis%20BRK%20Bereitschaft%20M%C3%BCnchberg.pdf).

This is a screenshot from my PdfFile:

[image: My Acro Fields]

Comment: *"My Fields in the PdfFile is empty."* - thus, there are no AcroForm firm fields in your pdf. At least no well-formed ones.

Comment: i have Form Fields in my PdfFile. Ive add these with Acrobat DC.

Comment: I added a Screenshot from my PdfFile

Comment: You say you added fields with Adobe Acrobat. What kind of form did you create? An acroform or an xfa form or a hybrid form? And is there anything special in the form like javascript snippets? Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: I added my File. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll look later.

Comment: Have you checked my file? :)

Comment: I doubt I'll find the time for that this year.

Comment: Your PDF has problems. Some tools and also preflight reports errors (inconsistent parent tree mapping). Please fix your PDF first. (Create a new PDF from Word and add the form fields again. For PDF creation use the SaveAs \ FileType: PDF option of word)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue cannot be reproduced.

#### Tested code

Obviously I could not test with your code as is because I don't have your variable values at hand, in particular not all those test fields. Thus, I used fixed strings instead:

```
Dim pdfreader As PdfReader = New PdfReader("Dienstnachweis BRK Bereitschaft Münchberg.pdf")
Dim pdfStamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(pdfreader, New FileStream("Dienstnachweis BRK Bereitschaft Münchberg-filled.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite), "\0", True)
pdfreader.RemoveUsageRights()
Dim pdfformfields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields
pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Datum", "txtdatum.Text")
pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Veranstaltung", "txtdatum.Text")
pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Dienstverantwortlicher", "txtel.Text")
pdfformfields.SetField("Datum", "txtdatum.Text", "txtdatum.Text", True)
pdfformfields.SetField("Veranstaltung", "txtdienstname.Text", "txtdienstname.Text", True)
pdfformfields.SetField("Ort", "txtdienstname.Text", "txtdienstname.Text", True)
pdfformfields.SetField("Dienstverantworlicher", "txtel.Text", "txtel.Text", True)
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = False

pdfStamper.Close()
pdfreader.Close()
```

#### The result

Running the code above with your example PDF in the current work directory I get a result PDF which is displayed like this in a current PDF Acrobat Reader:

[image: screen shot]

Thus, the fields are properly filled. I also checked the PDF internally, e.g. the field "Datum":

[image: structure]

As you can see, the text "txtdatum.Text" is also present as value of the abstract field (the **V** value), not only in the appearance.